# Is there a way to create a horizontally scrollable container without using a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to create a scrollable DIV that does not wrap without using a table.  Here's what I've tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
DIV { width: 100px; height: 50px; overflow: auto; }
UL LI { float: left; border: 1px solid; }
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/JGZJj/

However, the list of items will still wrap to a new line once it passes the 100px div.  If I try the same thing with a table, for example:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Item</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
DIV { width: 100px; height: 50px; overflow: auto; }
TR TD { border: 1px solid; }
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kWwER/

Then all items display on a single row and do not wrap.  Is there a way to get this behavior without using a TABLE tag?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:scroll;`?

Comment: Yup, the contents still wrap with `overflow: scroll;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your CSS (assuming use of ul/li tags) from:

```
div { width: 100px; height: 50px; overflow: auto; }
li { border: 1px solid; }
```

to:

```
div { width: 100px; height: 50px; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap; }
li { border: 1px solid; display: inline; }
```

That should take care of it for you. Here's the [jsFiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/jwiscarson/tjy6e/1/).

**As an aside:** I'd like to add that you should avoid selectors like `TR TD` or `UL LI` whenever possible.

1. `<li>` and `<td>` tags should always follow `<tr>` and `<ul>` tags.
2. Descendant selectors [are really expensive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/writing_efficient_css#Avoid_the_descendant_selector).

In these situations, you're asking the browser to look for any `<td>` tag that's any descendant of any `<tr>` tag, so it's looking through every level of hierarchy beneath every `<tr>` tag. If you **absolutely have to** use descendants, try to limit them to one level of hierarchy by using a selector like `tr > td`. Even better would be to assign a class to the elements you want to modify, and write your CSS against that selector.

Comment: Excellent!  This is what I was after.  The CSS was just for example purposes, this is in no way what my production code looks like :)

Comment: Whew! Great to hear. I always assume ignorance, because some of my first selectors were...well...worse than the examples on that Mozilla page. :)

Answer (score 0):

On any block element with a fixed height, put the css attribute `overflow:scroll`

Should make your element scrollable with a scrollbar when it's contents bust the fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but have you tried using `display: table;` on your containing `div`, and `display: table-cell` on your `li` elements.

[**Example fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/JGZJj/1/)

Comment: For some reason when I try that, I can no longer get it to scroll.  It just ignores the width of the div.

Answer (score 0):

after your first  tag add this

```
<div id="menu_wrap">
```

then in your css add

```
#menu_wrap {width: 682px;}
```

this will be your result https://jsfiddle.net/JGZJj/4/

Comment: Interesting - Wonder why that works.  It's like another layer of DIV will stop it from wrapping.

Comment: Never mind, that solution doesn't scale.  You'd have to know how many items you have in the list, otherwise it starts wrapping after 682 pixels.

Comment: the second div is setting the width of the <ul> otherwise it inherits the first div if 100px